# PyroCMS custom libraries and CI SuperObject

Tags: codeigniter, pyrocms

It should be simple, but it's not.

I have a library that is hoping to use other libraries, but something ain't jiving.

Both libs live in system/cms/libraries because as far as I can tell, addons/shared_addons/libraries is utterly useless and the libraries need to be autoloaded (it seems that system/cms is essentially system/application but please correct me if wrong). An aside: just for kicks I put a library in shared_addons/libaries just to see if I could call if from a module; I couldn't. Why is it there?

Lib1
-needs db
-needs lib2

Lib2
-needs session

Here's what happens. Controller [module] loads; calls lib1 which calls lib2 which throws an error. Lib1 is to be called by all module controllers. Lib2 uses session data that is set earlier on and is only called by lib1.

In lib2 I use $CI=get_instance() to supposedly enable CI libs (e.g. database, session). However, I can't get past "Fatal error: Call to a member function userdata() on a non-object"; which is called by

```
//system/cms/libraries/lib2.php
$this->CI =& get_instance();
//$this->load->library('database'); == "can't find class database"
$ekeyLoc = $this->CI->session->userdata('ronery');
```

now if I run this in a module controller, it works as expected.

So googling that error, a lot of "db not loaded"'s come up. Just to make sure, I tried to load the database, but because eff me, it can't find class 'database' NB: database is being autoloaded.

When you assign CodeIgniter super object, I'm assuming it's grabbing the whole jabloney, right? I thought so. But to make sure, I decided to try and load the database class in a module/controller, which turns out, because eff me, couldn't be found.

I tried looking through the pyroCMS docs to find out about any trickery, but there ain't much, and none helpful to my situation.

Why can't I load a core library from a module controller?

Why can't I load a core library into a custom library in system/cms/libraries?

Why doesn't the CodeIgniter super object I assign contain session/db crap?

Why can't I load a library from /addons/shared_addons/library?

Why would a call to `$this->session->userdata()` work from a module controller, but not from a library in the system/cms/libraries folder even though CodeIgniter super object has been assigned?

Thanks.

---

After 2 days with no answer, I find it both frustrating and hilarious that continuing to search for help inevitably leads to this question being the top google result. FML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first:

```
$this->load->library('database');
```

That is not valid CodeIgniter code, like their documentation says it should be:

```
$this->load->database();
```

As you've already pointed out though this is autoloaded so there is no need to do that anyway.

**Why can't I load a core library from a module controller?**

You can.

**Why can't I load a core library into a custom library in system/cms/libraries?**

You can.

**Why doesn't the CodeIgniter super object I assign contain session/db crap?**

It does.

**Why can't I load a library from /addons/shared_addons/library?**

This was not possible in 1.3.x but should have been fixed in 1.3.2, if not has been fixed since in 2.0.

I do not know what you are doing or why you are having such problems, but without any example code or a description of what version of PyroCMS you are using I cannot help any further.

If you have been stuck for two days why have you not posted on our forums? If you HAVE posted on our forums (I didn't see anything about it) you should have put a link in this post to your forum thread to help other people answer the questions.

This is not the first time anyone has been stuck on the internet but you act like it is. Come on, you know how this works! :)

Comment: My issue (I think, and in this case) was I copied the lib into the module libraries folders and so was modifying one, not the others, and was wondering about moving to Tibet. I understand I'm not the first to get stuck. However, I tend to become epically cunty when I can't figure things out (though I try to maintain my sense of humour). It doesn't help that the documentation is... lacking... but that is my problem; a better understanding of the framework/cms is needed on my part and coincidentally is what I'm getting. Cheers.